# How to apply setting by toggle switch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, button, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can anyone tell me how to use switch ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639372/can-anyone-tell-me-how-to-use-switch)

Hi I have two view

the first view contains the main function and the second view is used to let the user change the setting on the first view.

I have insert a switch in second view to let user change a setting on the first view

I have two questions, how to use switch to set YES and NO for a value? and then, base on that value 
the first view will respond differently?

P.S. I change the view with navigation method , not add subview

Thanks in advance

lets say I have the following code

First View.m

```
- (IBAction) addValue:(id)sender
{
aValue ++;
}
//the following will react according to the setting on second view
If (????//Don't know what to put here to represent the switch is ON or OFF)
{ //whatever action}
else
{//whatever action}
```

second view.h

```
@interface
    //declaration of the switch
        - (IBAction) changeMode:(id)sender
    @end
```

second view.m

```
    -(IBAction) changeMode:(id)sender
{
    //What to put here to switch ON and OFF ??
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
if ( self.mySwitch.on )
// do something
```

Here I assume mySwitch is an instance of UISwitch. It is a good idea to store switch value to NSUserDefaults so that you can retrieve it from another view.

This is how you store the value:

```
NSString *switchValue; 
if ( self.mySwitch.on ) 
    switchValue = @"YES";
else 
    switchValue = @"NO";

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:switchValue forKey:@"switchValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This is how you retrieve the value:

```
BOOL switchState = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"switchValue"] boolValue];
```

Comment: umum sorry, is there anything you can relate to my code ?

Comment: ok I compile it without problem, but I find that when I switch back to First view after i toggle the switch to OFF, and again to the second view( where the switch button is) it doesn't store the state, it still "ON".

Comment: You should set the switch in viewDidLoad method by reading from NSUserDefaults after it was changed first by the user.