# can anyone tell me how to use switch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, button, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply setting by toggle switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637799/how-to-apply-setting-by-toggle-switch)

I want to use switch button to toggle on and off of a setting

can anyone tell me how to set it up? I already have the following code

Thanks!

declaration

```
- (IBAction) changeMode:(id)sender;
```

implementation

```
-(IBAction) changeMode:(id)sender
{
}
```

Comment: You asked this 2 hours ago and got an answer! Please don't repeat questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637799/how-to-apply-setting-by-toggle-switch

Comment: I don't agree i got the answer, i still dont understand, now i do

Comment: Then there are other things to do besides posting a duplicate question, the first of which is _be_  _patient_ because people here are volunteering to help you. Two hours is not a very long time. Further options are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: +1 for "be patient" and "don't post duplicates." Making excuses for bad behavior won't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you hook up the UISwitch in Interface Builder, you can check if it's on like this:

```
-(IBAction) changeMode:(id)sender
{
     if ([(UISwitch *)sender on])
     {
          NSLog(@"The switch is on.");
     }
     else
     {
          NSLog(@"The switch is off.");
     }
}
```